# How to unpack dictionary in order that it was passed?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, ordereddictionary

This is the following problem:

**main_module.py**

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from my_other_module import foo

a = OrderedDict([
    ('a', 1),
    ('b', 2),
    ('c', 3),
    ('d', 4),
    ])

foo(**a)
```

**my_other_module.py**

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        print k, v
```

When i run `main_module.py` I'm expecting to get printout with the order I specified:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
```

But instead I'm getting:

```
a 1
c 3
b 2
d 4
```

I do understand that this has something to do with the way `**` operator is implemented and somehow it looses order how dictionary pairs are passed in. Also I do understand that dictionaries in python are not ordered as lists are, because they're implemented as hash tables. Is there any kind of 'hack' that I could apply so I get the behaviour that is needed in this context?

P.S. - In my situation I can't sort the dictionary inside foo function since there are no rules which could be followed except strict order that values are passed in.

Comment: Why don't you just pass the `OrderedDict` as an ordinary argument, rather than as `**kwarg`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By using `**a` you're *unpacking* the ordered dictionary into an argument dictionary.

So when you enter in `foo`, `kwargs` is just a plain dictionary, with order not guaranteed (unless you're using Python 3.6+, but that's still an implementation detail in 3.6 - the ordering becomes official in 3.7: [Are dictionaries ordered in Python 3.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6))

You could just lose the packing/unpacking in that case so it's portable for older versions of python.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def foo(kwargs):
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        print(k, v)

a = OrderedDict([
    ('a', 1),
    ('b', 2),
    ('c', 3),
    ('d', 4),
    ])

foo(a)
```

Comment: Well we wanted to support the case when someone calls `foo` like this: `foo(argument='value')`. By doing what you suggested we will strictly have to pass dictionary type to `foo`. If there aren't any other solutions I guess this is the only valid one.

Comment: in `foo(argument1='value', argument2='value2')`, if you map to `**kwargs` it's the exact same order issue. Unless you're enforcing python 3.6+ where the issue is gone.